# JIRA Custom field not rendering Rich Text

Tags: jira

I have created two custom fields on a JIRA story that I need rich text entry. The problem is that one is rendering correctly and the other isn't as can be see by the following images.

Both as can be seen are setup 'Text Field Multi-line' - exhausted all other lines of enquiry

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The field has probably not the correct field renderer configured.

Settings --> Issues --> Field Configurations --> Your used field configuration

Now look for your field and click the "Renderers" link to select the "Wiki Style Renderer".

Comment: Thanks but I'm afraid I have tried that to no avail - default renderer for multi line field should have rich text editing as default. The problem here is that I have created two custom fields identically but they are rendering differently.

Comment: The  "default text renderer" does not render Rich text. You have to select "Wiki Style Renderer" to have rich text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Text Field, and convert it to WIKI style text field. This way you will be able to post URL.

Here is 5 minute video which I have created on how to do this.

https://youtu.be/QCNHPy88iKA

I hope it helps.